# Restrict address range accessible by Eclipse/GDB

Tags: eclipse, embedded, gdb

I'm using Eclipse for debugging on an embedded CPU that has a painful quirk: when it tries to access a memory region that is unimplemented, the CPU hangs.

Occasionally when debugging, the debugger tries to follow a bad address and hangs the CPU.  Is there any way to tell GDB that it must never try to read memory from, say, 0x40020000 to 0x4fffffff ?

Comment: That behavior is much more normal than you might expect. Many CPUs require the bus transaction to be terminated by the device that handled it. If there is no such device that recognizes the address, then the cycle will never terminate. This is quite common in  ColdFire devices, and I've seen it in other systems as well. It can be handy to have a pushbutton available that will signal a transaction end that you can push after you make the mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps setting [Memory Region Attributes](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory-Region-Attributes.html) will help.

Comment: Excellent.  That does look like what I need, though I think I need to upgrade my version of GDB to one that supports 'set mem inaccessible-by-default'.